# Java : Only the first if-statement working

Tags: java, if-statement

So, I tried to make a simple pythagoras app that can measure the side length of a triangle after inputting the length of the 2 other sides. To measure that side, user supposed to input 'x' or 'X' into one of three sides of the triangle. Here's my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class pythagoras_1 {
    public static void main (String Args[]){
    //string data type to check user input 'x' or not
    String  shypo,scat1,scat2;
    double  hypo, cat1, cat2;
    boolean hypoSelected, cat1Selected, cat2Selected;

    Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print( "Hypotenuse = ");
    shypo = console.next();

    System.out.print("Cathetus 1 = ");
    scat1 = console.next();

    System.out.print("Cathetus 2 = ");
    scat2 = console.next();

    hypoSelected = shypo.equals("x")||shypo.equals("X");
    cat1Selected = scat1.equals("x")||scat1.equals("X");
    cat2Selected = scat2.equals("x")||scat2.equals("X");

    if(hypoSelected){
        cat1 = Double.parseDouble(scat1);
        cat2 = Double.parseDouble(scat2);
        System.out.println("Hypotenuse = "+ hypoC(cat1,cat2));
    }
    else if(cat1Selected){
        hypo = Double.parseDouble(shypo);
        cat2 = Double.parseDouble(scat2);
        System.out.println("cathetus 1 = "+ Cat1C(hypo,cat2));
    }
    else if(cat2Selected){  
        hypo = Double.parseDouble(shypo);
        cat1 = Double.parseDouble(scat1);
        System.out.println("cathetus 2 = "+ Cat2C(hypo,cat1));
    }
    else{
        System.err.println("ERROR");
    }
}

//HERE THE METHOD FUNCTION
public static double hypoC(double cat1,double cat2){
    double ohypo;
    ohypo = Math.sqrt((cat1*cat1)+(cat2*cat2));
    return ohypo;
}
public static double Cat1C(double hypo,double cat2){
    double ocat1;
    ocat1 = Math.sqrt((hypo*hypo)-(cat2*cat2));
    return ocat1;
}
public static double Cat2C(double hypo,double cat1){
    double ocat2;
    ocat2 = Math.sqrt((hypo*hypo)-(cat1*cat1));
    return ocat2;
}
}
```

But it works only on hypotenuse(the first if-statement), if I input 'x' on cathetus 1 or 2 the app ends without executing the code. How can I fix this?

here's the output when  scat1 or scat 2 value is 'x'

```
 run:
 Hypotenuse = 5
 Cathetus 1 = 4
 Cathetus 2 = x
 ERROR
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

here's the output when  shypo is 'x'

```
 run:
 Hypotenuse = x
 Cathetus 1 = 4
 Cathetus 2 = 3  
 Hypotenuse = 5.0
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Comment: Have you debugged through the code? What are the values of `scat1` and `scat2`? Can you reproduce this with a [mcve] that doesn't use `Scanner`, or reproduce it in a [mcve] that *just* uses `Scanner` and prints out the inputs? (I suspect your `cat2Selected` code is intended to use `scat2`, btw...)

Comment: Is this the actual code you using? Where is shipo declared?

Comment: no actually, I tried to convert hipotenusa(indonesian languange) to Hypotenuse. so that's why there's a little typo there

Comment: The point is nobody can help unless they know exactly what your code says. You claim the code "works" to calculate the hypotenuse, but I don't think it does because even after correcting typos Double.parseDouble("x") would throw a NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error i was getting in your code were typo's and parsing exception since it was trying to parse x to double, that's the reason it was not executing code.
check logs of your program for that.

Corrected Main function of your program

```
public static void main(String Args[]) {
        String shypo, scat1, scat2;
        Scanner console = null;
        try {
            console = new Scanner(System.in);
            // input of each side
            System.out.print("hypotenuse = ");
            shypo = console.next();

            System.out.print("cathetus 1 = ");
            scat1 = console.next();

            System.out.print("cathetus 2 = ");
            scat2 = console.next();

            if ("x".equalsIgnoreCase(shypo)) {
                System.out.println("Hypotenuse = " + hypoC(Double.parseDouble(scat1), Double.parseDouble(scat2)));
            } else if ("x".equalsIgnoreCase(scat1)) {
                System.out.println("cathetus 1 = " + Cat1C(Double.parseDouble(shypo), Double.parseDouble(scat2)));
            } else if ("x".equalsIgnoreCase(scat2)) {
                System.out.println("cathetus 2 = " + Cat2C(Double.parseDouble(shypo), Double.parseDouble(scat1)));
            } else {
                System.err.println("ERROR");
            }
        } finally {
            if (console != null)
                console.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got loads of typos:

```
cat2Selected = scat1.equals("x")||scat1.equals("X");
```

Change `scat1` to `scat2`

This is the key one:

```
  hypo = Double.parseDouble(shipo);
```

`shipo` should be `shypo`, as otherwise `hypo` is undefined in calls to `Cat1C` or `Cat2C`. and further, `'x'` is not going to parse as a `Double`. You could place the definitions of `hypo`, `cat1` and `cat2` inside the condition.

Finally:

```
 ohipo = Math.sqrt((cat1*cat1)+(cat2*cat2));
```

`ohipo` should be `ohypo`.

Comment: actually the code was converted from indonesian language.. so there's a little bit of typo there I'm sorry

Comment: Please paste the exact code you are using. It's impossible to answer without it.

Comment: Look very carefully at the line     cat2Selected = scat1.equals("x")||scat1.equals("X");

Comment: oh god, thank you so much.I wasn't aware of that @cppbeginner